# Why are WeightedAdjacencyMatrix and WeightedAdjacencyGraph inconsistent?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a weighted adjacent matrix of a graph:

```
weightedMatrix]={{0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 
   0, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

But when I try `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[weightedMatrix]`, I see:

[image]

Why? I also try to use `AdjacencyGraph[weightedMatrix]`,

but now it shows me that AdjacencyGraph::inv: The argument {{0,0,0,1,-1,1},{0,0,0,1,1,-1},{0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1,1},{-1,1,0,1,0,0},{1,-1,1,1,0,0}} in AdjacencyGraph[Automatic,{{0,0,0,1,-1,1},{0,0,0,1,1,-1},{0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1,1},{-1,1,0,1,0,0},{1,-1,1,1,0,0}}] is not a valid adjacency matrix.

So, how do I do it?

---

**As Domen mentioned,** we should instead use something like: `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[weightedMatrix /. 0 -> ∞].` While it worked, what's even stranger is that a function that seems to be the opposite of `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`, `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix`, does not use infinity (uses 0) to represent non-adjacency between two vertices.  This inconsistency is quite frustrating, especially when transferring between graphs and matrices.

Domen also reminded  me this link regarding the same question in [wolfram community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060252.)https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060252.

Comment: Please look at the examples in the documentation for [`WeightedAdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedAdjacencyGraph.html). Then, you will realize that you should instead use something like: `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[weightedMatrix /. 0 -> ∞]`.

Comment: @Domen Thanks. I see. But what surprises me even more is that, for non-adjacent vertices, the assignment of infinity is not mentioned at all in the documentation.

Comment: @Domen Let `g= WeightedAdjacencyGraph[weightedMatrix /. 0 -> ∞]`. More interesting thing is after running `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g] // Normal`, you will see `{{0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0}}`  Why is there such inconsistency between input and output?

Comment: Then, I suggest you rewrite the whole question to be focused on this particular discrepancy. You can help yourself with a similar (unanswered) question on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060252). (For example, rename the title to something like _Inconsistency between WeightedAdjacencyMatrix and WeightedAdjacencyGraph_.)

Comment: Okay, I discovered this issue when transmitting matrices. It seems like Szabolcs Horvát noticed this problem a long time ago.